# Why vue-router doesn't show component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

***DISCLAIMER!** This code is for private using, so it can consist wheels*

I do this task without webpack or etc.

I'm trying to make component loader.
Well, getComponents() works fine and returns html code in string. When i open /userlists, router shows nothing. So, route / shouldn't work too, but it work! Where i made a mistake?

loader:

```
const getComponent = name => {
    return document.getElementsByClassName('component '+name)[0].outerHTML
}

const mainComponent = {
    template: '<h3>Hand mailer<p>)</p></h3>'
}

const userLists = {
    template: getComponent('userslist')
}
```

component:

```
<div class="component userlists">
        <p>
            Hello vue!
        </p>
    </div>
```

router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    hashbang: true,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: mainComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/userlists',
            component: userLists
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: i am not sure but the docs say it's not "hasbang" its "mode"
for example check this:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html
maybe this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault, I'ce added property `display: none;` to class components)))